# How to Store multidimensional array into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

i have created a database called "test" and create a table called "biodata". I have created 3 columns called "Name" "Age" and "Description" into biodata table. Now how to store my array result into each column.

Below is the complete code...

```
<?php

    $ip = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $res = mysql_connect($ip,$username,$password);
    if(!$res)
    {
        echo "DB Connection Failed.";
        exit;
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db("test"))
    {
        echo "NOT SELECTED";
        exit;
    }

        $company =  array(
                    'Record1'=>array('Shabbir',26,'Designer'),
                    'Record2'=>array('Burhan',24,'Architecture'),
                    'Record3'=>array('Huzeifa',20,'Accountant'),
                );

        foreach ($company as $employees=>$details){

        echo '<strong>'.$employees.'</strong><br>';

        foreach($details as $employeeinfo){

            echo $employeeinfo.'<br>';

        }

        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO biodata (Name, Age, Description) VALUES ($employeeinfo[0], $employeeinfo[1], '$employeeinfo[2]')";
        mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mysql_query` is suppose to be inside your `foreach` statement ... you also need to sanitize your data because of `SQL Injection`

you also don't need 2 `foreach` statement ...

**Correction**

```
foreach ($company as $employees =>$details){
    echo '<strong>'.$employees.' - OK</strong><br>';
    mysql_query(sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($details[0]),mysql_real_escape_string($details[1]),mysql_real_escape_string($details[2])));
}
```

**Full Script Arrangement**

```
$ip = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$res = mysql_connect($ip,$username,$password);
$sql = "INSERT INTO biodata (Name, Age, Description) VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%s')";
$company =  array(
        'Record1'=>array('Shabbir',26,'Designer'),
        'Record2'=>array('Burhan',24,'Architecture'),
        'Record3'=>array('Huzeifa',20,'Accountant'),
);

if(!$res)
{
    echo "DB Connection Failed.";
    exit;
}

if(!mysql_select_db("test"))
{
    echo "NOT SELECTED";
    exit;
}

foreach ($company as $employees =>$details){
    echo '<strong>'.$employees.' - OK</strong><br>';
    mysql_query(sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($details[0]),mysql_real_escape_string($details[1]),mysql_real_escape_string($details[2])));
}
```

Comment: can yo please explain me why you use '%s' into VALUES??

Comment: I was trying to format the values properly .. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for more information on `sprintf` ... I glad it worked for you ... don't forget to accept

Comment: Now i want to retrive the data from mysql and want to display on webpage? is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

A side note. No matter how small your loops are (low number of iterations) do not put queries inside of it. Instead use loops only to construct one complex query containing all the data and then execute the query outside the loop.

**EDIT:** Example of a query you could construct in a loop.

```
INSERT INTO table 
    (name, age, position)
VALUES
   ('Shabbir', 26, 'Designer'),
   ('Burhan', 24, 'Architecture'),
   ('Huzeifa', 20, 'Accountant');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is just in the wrong place:

```
foreach ($company as $employees=>$details)
{
    echo '<strong>'.$employees.'</strong><br>';
        foreach($details as $employeeinfo)
        {
            echo $employeeinfo.'<br>';
        }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO biodata (Name, Age, Description) VALUES ($details[0], $details[1], '$details[2]')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Hey Guyz there is something more i want to retrive the data from mysql and want to display on webpage?